# Simple Korn shell script needed to list out all files created/modified after tidemark date

Tags: bash, shell-script

How to list out all files created/modified after a particular tidemark date?
If my tidemark date is '30-May-2016 08:06:49' then I need all files/directories generated/modified after that date&time.

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: and what is your OS?

Comment: Bash (as per your tags) or ksh (as per your title)? In a single directory, or exploring directories recursively? On what Unix variant?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you check for all files modified today (since 00:00):

```
touch -t `date +%m%d0000` /tmp/$$
find . -cnewer /tmp/$$
```

OR in general:

```
touch -t YYMMDDhhmm.SS /tmp/timestamp
find directory -type f -newer /tmp/timestamp
rm /tmp/timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

If on a recent GNU or BSD system, you can use:

```
find . -newermt '2016-05-30 08:06:49'
```